# Upgrade to Windows 7 - External Monitor not working

Tags: windows-7

I upgraded my computer to Windows 7 today, and now I can't figure out how to detect my external monitors. I go into the displays and press "detect" but nothing is happening. The monitor just says "no signal." Is there something special I need to do? It used to always work on what I had before (Windows Vista).

Also, no drivers are needed for this monitor. When I first bought this monitor, I didn't have to install anything. I just plugged it in to my Windows Vista and it detected it fine.

In fact, I tried two seperate monitors which I have used with my machine prior to upgrading to windows 7 (neither of them requiring drivers). Still nothing.

I've tried the win+p trick, but nothing popped up when doing that.

I also restarted my computer with both monitors plugged in. Still didn't work.

Comment: did you try the "win key + P" shortcut?

Comment: yes, I tried that. no pop up boxes showed up

Comment: Did you check the cables? I've seen the most obvious sometimes be the right answer :p

Comment: of course I checked the cables :)

Comment: in fact, I tried two seperate monitors which I have both used before upgrading to windows 7

Comment: Interesting... Could this be related to the graphics card?

Comment: I don't think so, because this same computer worked with both monitors prior to upgrading to windows 7.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but the graphics card might require a special driver for Seven. My WiFi card did :/

Comment: oh, how can I find out?

Comment: Well, now I'm on a MacBookAir so I can't check, but there is a display somewhere in Seven that lists the hardware and shows what doesn't have the required drivers.

Comment: got it! updated the driver and it works. woohoo thanks!! one other question. the monitor sort of goes out of the range of the monitor. I mean, i can drag my mouse above the bounds of the monitor (on my external monitor) how do I fix this/

Comment: Can be due to Windows (see appropriate panel), to the CG (Nvidia for example has an utility for that sort of tweaking) or the monitor (there should be a physical button on it for setting the viewport). Good luck!

Comment: @Kheldar - please update this question with your resolution, so that we can close it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to update the driver. Search online to figure out how to have Windows update your drivers, and then go from there.